# PHP Get URL Of Current Page, Not Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I realise this might look like a duplicate but I don't think it is. I've looked everywhere.

What I'm attempting to do is get the URL of the page the user is currently on, but I'm attempting to do this in a separately loaded page.

`$('#siteStatus').load('/_backend/account/accountStatus.php');`

I want to load a script into this div that works out the current page of the url.

At the moment I am doing `$url = "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";` but this just returns `/_backend/account/` and I'm unsure why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try this `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` for full document path.or `print_r($_SERVER);` and choose what property you are need from the array

Comment: @prasad This returns `var/www`

Comment: .its working good ...What you have expect from that?

Comment: I'm currently on `/home.php` but this script either displays `var/www` with your recommendation or `/_backend/account` without it. I want it to display `/home.php` if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @prasad using `print_r($_SERVER);` showed an array of what I could use and it turns out `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` was what I needed.

Thanks.